# Using select form with JSON to make content appear

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I am trying to make a selection form, where depending on the select field chosen, I want different information to appear.  Here is the way I'd like to represent it:

```
<form id="myForm">
<select name="options" form="myForm">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</form>

<!-- The following will be invisible until selection choice is made -->
<h1>option.name</h1>
<p>option.info</p>
```

Then, in JSON, I'd like the store the following content.  I am using this as the handler just to test it out:

```
<script>

var data =  {
  "option1" : {
     "name" : "Option 1",
     "info" : "I'm glad you've chosen Option 1"
  },
  "option2" : {
     "name" : "Option 2",
     "info" : "Not a bad choice, either"
  }
};

var myForm = document.getElementById('options');


myForm.addEventListener("change", function() {
    val = this.value;
    alert(data[val][name]);


}, false);

})();

</script>
```

The output of the alert is empty.

Comment: show what you've tried.

Comment: a) add onchange/onclick/onwhatever handler to your select. b) when triggered, have the handler get the selected value, look it up in your json list, and populate your two h1/p options with the lookupped data.

Comment: I've updated my main answer with an attempt.

Comment: I don't see you define `data` anywhere, but the error is pretty clear: `data` doesn't have a property called `val`.

Comment: *"The output of the alert is empty."* You seem to be trying to use the value of `window.name` as property value. `window.name` is usually an empty string. I guess you want `data[val].name`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm mixing up my array/object accessing.  And the JSON was stored in a data variable.